# Logging serial port data which is used by another process

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a third party tool, which allows us to connect to a device via serial port. To connect the device, the tool sends a signal via serial port. We need to know what signal was sent via serial port. We need that data for implementing some other logic. Please suggest me.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to setup virtual serial ports using something like http://com0com.sourceforge.net/ then say the real serial port is COM1

do COM1 <--> your app <--> VIRTUALCOM1 <-- virtual connection -> VirtualCOM2 <---- third party tool

your app passes data between virtual com and COM1 and then can intercept any data you like

Comment: +1 for mentioning exactly the same tool i would use for it. ;)